# Issues when using while loop

Tags: ios, swift

When I use a simple while loop like the one below, my app's UI will freeze:

```
func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  while(true){
  print(CheckDB());
  }
}
```

Again, the program with that one is that the UI freezes but it does output the data. When I try to make it asynchronous the UI does not freeze and my data is still being printed, but the problem now is that adjusting a slider I have in my UI does not do anything when it should be printing the number it is at, so while the UI does work at that point, it is literally just the UI and nothing else.

```
func viewDidLoad(){
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
   while(true){
   super.viewDidLoad()
   print(CheckDB());
  }
}
```

So my question now is, how do I have a constant loop running in the background updating some UI elements like Labels without messing up other parts of the app?

Comment: `while(true){super.viewDidLoad()...}` NEVER EVER EVER do that.

Comment: Dispatch the code to update the UI to the main thread, but I hope this is a theoretical example and you don't poll seriously a database this way.

Comment: if you're trying to update UI when you adjust the slider, use a protocol/delegate to signal the UI to update when the slider moves. If you're trying to update UI every n number of seconds, you can use an NSTimer to call a refresh method after however many seconds you want pass.

Comment: Your code is a hopeless mess. You should not call viewDidLoad directly. The system calls that method, and it should only be called once in the life of a view controller. You should not create a while(true) loop like that. You should not call UI methods like viewDidLoad from a background thread.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do at a high level. We can help you if we know your goal, but as it is we can't tell what you're trying to do. You make mention of a slider but don't show that code. You have a function `CheckDB()` but you don't explain what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have some threading issues you need to work out, but this is generally a bad approach anyway.

If you need to change something in you UI when your DB changes, you should be using a notification or listener/delegate from the DB rather constantly checking in your VC.